# ValueError: too many values to unpack, passing a list as *args

Tags: python, django-filter

I have a problem passing arguments through a list to Django filter. Here my code:

```
args = [ "Q( title__icontains = 'Foo' ) | Q( author__icontains = 'Foo' )", "Q( title__icontains = 'Bar' ) | Q( author__icontains = 'Bar' )" ]
entries = Book.objects.filter( *args )
```

but `filter` returns this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack,

Comment: What is the relationship between the foo and bar queries? Are they supposed to be AND-ed or OR-ed together?

Comment: Here there is the relationship of predicates: `(title__icontains = 'foo' OR  author__icontains = 'Foo') AND (title__icontains = 'bar' OR  author__icontains = 'bar')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *args* are strings, but they must be `Q` objects. Remove the quotes around your `Q` object definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all " and you get it right.

```
args = [ Q( title__icontains = 'Foo' ) | Q( author__icontains = 'Foo' ), Q( title__icontains = 'Bar' ) | Q( author__icontains = 'Bar' )]
entries = Book.objects.filter( *args )
```